# Evaluate $\int_{e^{-2\pi n}}^1 \left|\left(\cos\left(\ln{1\over x}\right)\right)'\right|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> For $n \in \Bbb N$ evaluate:
>   $$
> I = \int_{e^{-2\pi n}}^1 \left|\left(\cos\left(\ln{1\over x}\right)\right)'\right|dx
> $$

This question appeared to be pretty complicated for me to handle. I've started by finding the derivate of the expression under integral sign. Let:
$$
g(x) = \cos\left(\ln {1\over x}\right)
$$
Then:
$$
{d(g(x))\over dx} = {\sin\left(\ln{1\over x}\right)\over x}
$$

From what I understand we need to find ranges of $x$ in which the derivative of $g(x)$ is greater than $0$ (or less than $0$). From this on, since $n$ is fixed and using the linearity property the integral is turned into a sum of integrals signs of which depend on the sign of $g'(x)$ (because of the absolute value). This is where I could not proceed.

The answer section suggests that $I = 4n$. The question is whether the general idea is correct and if so how can I finish this problem?

Comment: what restrictions on $n$ are in place here?

Comment: @clathratus none, except for $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: in that case, [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/clegkjnvji) may help.

Comment: Hint: Forget about absolute value first. And put the derivative under $d$ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand equals

$$\left | \frac{\sin (\ln x)}{x} \right |.$$

Make the change of variables $x=e^y.$ We'll then have $e^y$ downstairs and $dx=e^y\,dy$ upstairs. Nice! The new interval of integration is $[-2\pi n,0],$ so our integral equals

$$\tag 1\int_{-2\pi n}^0 |\sin y|\, dy.$$

Now $\int_0^{2\pi } |\sin y|\,dy = 4.$ So by $2\pi $–periodicity, $(1)$ equals $n\cdot 4=4n.$

Comment: Neat. Thank you!